# AWS Quick Sight - Query and data retrieval mechanism

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am new to Quick Sight. My understanding of Quick sight Query and retrieval is as below

1. Each graph in a sheet is a query by itself being fired to the database
2. The filters that are attached to a graph acts like a Where condition for data retrieval and not after data retrieval

Do I stand right here ? Please let me know

Musthafa

Comment: Look at the athena query history. You will see the complete queries fired by quicksight. From my experience, you are right in both 1) and 2) but the queries might be very complicated.

Comment: Thanks Peter Appreciate